# Illegal conversion from List<OpportunityLineItem> to List<Opportunity>

Tags: apex, code

Good day,

Still finding my way around Apex. Please assist with the mentioned error. I'm not sure what's wrong with my code. In essence, I'm trying to retrieve information from a related list(Opp Products) to my Case object

Any assistance will be appreciated:

````
public static List<Opportunity> getOppProducts()
    {
        List<OpportunityLineItem> item =
        [SELECT Product2Id,
                Product_Code__c,
                UnitPrice,
                Quantity,
                TotalPrice,
                Amount_Invoiced__c,
                Price_Plan__c
        FROM    OpportunityLineItem
        ];
       return item;
    }```
````

Comment: You just have to change the return type of the method to `List<OpportunityLineItem>`, currently, it expects the method to return a list of Opportunities, but you are, in fact, returning a list of Opportunity Line Items.

Comment: rael_kid, you should move your comment to answer

Comment: @rael_kid thanks, but what do I change the return type to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to change the return type of the method to `List<OpportunityLineItem>`, currently, it expects the method to return a list of Opportunities, but you are, in fact, returning a list of Opportunity Line Items

So your method will look like this:

```
public static List<OpportunityLineItem> getOppProducts()
{
    List<OpportunityLineItem> item =
    [SELECT Product2Id,
            Product_Code__c,
            UnitPrice,
            Quantity,
            TotalPrice,
            Amount_Invoiced__c,
            Price_Plan__c
    FROM OpportunityLineItem];
   return item;
}
```

The method declaration consists (in this case) out of four parts:

`public` is the visibility, in this case it'll be visible for all code in this namespace (so the other classes/triggers).

`static` means it should be called from a static context. So you can not call this method using an instance of this class, but only by refencing the class by its name.

`List<Opportunity>` is the return type. This is what you should change to `List<OpportunityLineItem>`. This lets the system know what data type the method returns. In your case, the return statement at the bottom returns an instance of a list of Opportunity Line Items. That should be consistent with the return type in the method declaration.

and finally, `getOppProducts` is the name of the method. Obviously, this is what you use when you want to call the method.

For some more information on how to declare, define, implement and call methods check the documentation; https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_defining_methods.htm

Comment: That will not make your code work better but since your query will/might return more than 1 record, you should name your variable items, not item.

Comment: Agreed, and the query should probably have some sort of filter, OP probably doesn't want to query all the opportunity lines all the time.

Comment: @rael_kid Thanks a lot guys, this really helped. I'm getting a Query for Too many rows. But I will sort that out...